# Is there a way to block javascript from an iframe pointing to a different domain?

Tags: javascript, iframe, ublock

I'm trying to add a custom filter using ublock origin to stop javascript from working on a specific iframe from a webpage.

#### Example

Accessing *example.com*, there's an iframe pointing to *annoyingData.com*. This other website has information I want but javascript I dislike. Is there a way to block only the javascript inside this other domain?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this need to be limited to iframes, or can it be applied to _any_ kind of visit to `annoyingData.com`?

Comment: In my specific case, it wouldn't hurt if it applies on any kind of visit.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of uBlock Origin can disable JavaScript from one site,
but you will need to visit it once to activate.

Click on the uBlock Origin icon to display the main interface. The new option to disable JavaScript for the site in the bottom-right corner and the icon looks like a closed tag `</>`.

A click disables JavaScript on the site and adds a red cross to the icon to indicate that JavaScript is turned off on this site. This is temporary, unless you make the change permanent using icons that uBlock Origin displays after you activate the option.

Source : [uBlock Origin can block JavaScript by default now](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/09/25/ublock-origin-can-block-javascript-by-default-now/).

[image]

Comment: I went to annoyingData.com, disabled javascript there and came back to example.com. Javascript is still running there. Did I miss something?

Comment: Probably not. Disabling JavaScript is a new feature on uBlock Origin so it can be still only partially implemented. It seems, according to your findings, that at the moment it may only block JavaScript from the primary website but not from secondary ones. You might send them a message, if there is such an option. Otherwise, you might use some other blocking add-on, such as NoScript or YesScript.